# Implicit decleration of function Clion Remote

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I am working on remote development on Raspberry Pi by using Clion.
The above code does not give any compile error, but Clion IDE gives the "implicit declaration invalid" warning.

Same problem occurs with pthread, string functions.

How can I fix it?

I am posting a picture of the IDE error, since this is not a compile error.

[image]

And here is my Cmake file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(untitled C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(untitled main.c)
```

Comment: Does it compile? You have correctly included `sys/socket.h`, so it should work. I would say your IDE is misconfigured.

Comment: Yes, it compiles and runs well. To make it simple, I posted a small piece of code here. In my big project, every library included well but IDE gives these errors. (For pthread library, string library, same error occurs.)

Comment: Not familiar with CLion, but would guess the include paths are not set up properly in the project settings.

Comment: Include path is /usr/include. Is it wrong?